# C# Homework Problem. User entered 7 weekly temperaturesto put into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a homework problem for the school. The user is to enter 7 temperatures. These temperatures are to be displayed back to the user and then the average temperature of the 7 is to be displayed. When I am working on the problem I am running into the problem that 1 of the temperatures that were entered is not being registered into the array. I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
class Program
{
    private static double[] temperatureArray = new double[10];

    static void Main()
    {
        Heading();
        TempInput();
        Read();
    }

    private static void Heading()
    {
        WriteLine("\t Weekly Temerature Report");
        WriteLine("\t " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        WriteLine("Enter 7 Temperatures");
        WriteLine("**********************************************");
    }

    private static void TempInput()
    {
        double total = 0;;
        string inputValue;
        int i = 0;
        int number;
        double average = 0;
        double ctr = 1;
        Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr);
        inputValue = ReadLine(); 
 
        while (ctr <= 7)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(inputValue, out number) == false)
            {
                WriteLine("Invalid input");
                i -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //good input
                temperatureArray[i] = double.Parse(inputValue);
                i += 1;
                ctr += 1;
                Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr );
                inputValue = ReadLine();
            }               
        }

        for (int n = 0; n<i;n++)
        {
            WriteLine(temperatureArray[n]);
            total += temperatureArray[n];
            average = total / 7;               
        }

        Write("average temp is {0}", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `temperatureArray` definition?

Comment: Looks like you're close with the code you've included, but we need to a bit more to make it a [mcve]. Ideally we should be able to paste this code into our own IDE and run it and get the same issue you're getting.

Comment: No need to decrement i since if it is not getting incremented when you have bad inputs : i -= 1;

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code is structured in a way that the last input is never added to the temperatureArray. When you ask for the last input then the variable *ctr* has already reached the value that exits the loop (7) So the code exits the loop without inserting the last value in the array.

A fast fix could be to add this line after the loop exit

```
     while(ctr < 7)
     {
        .....
        else
        {
            //good input
            temperatureArray[i] = double.Parse(inputValue);
            i += 1;
            ctr += 1;
            Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr );
            inputValue = ReadLine();
        }               
    }
    // catch the last input.
    temperatureArray[i] = double.Parse(inputValue);
```

but a better approach is to restructure your code and ask for the input immediately when you enter the loop

```
   while(ctr <  7)
   {
      Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr);
      inputValue = ReadLine(); 
      if(!double.TryParse(inputValue, out double temp))
      {
           WriteLine("Error");
           continue;
      }
      else
      {
          temperatureArray[ctr] = temp;
          ctr++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Alex Of course, but I guess it is still a little too early to introduce Linq into the curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

Move this code inside a loop

```
Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr);
inputValue = ReadLine();
```

So, the loop will be something like that:

```
while (ctr <= 7)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Temperature {0} ", ctr);
    inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(inputValue, out number) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    }
    else
    {
        //good input
        temperatureArray[i] = double.Parse(inputValue);
        i += 1;
        ctr += 1;
    }

}
```

Here, at first, we read the input, then validate it.